# iOS share data through keychain using Delphi

Tags: ios, delphi, keychain, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

So it is definitely possible to share data through the KeyChain. My problem now is to implement this with Firemonkey using Delphi.  First, Is there a proper library or API to use with Firemonkey to share keys?  Second, is there any sample code on doing this via Delphi?

Comment: Did you find ant thing? I have the same problem.

Comment: No I do not think they have implemented that part in their libraries yet.  I am sure there must be some workaround, but up until now I have failed to get it working.